# PageRequestManager not populating 'args._postBackElement' parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, pagerequestmanager

When using an ASP.NET UpdatePanel and causing a postback while a previous postback is still in-progress, the default action is to cancel the first and allow the second to take over.

I've built a mechanism to do the opposite: to leave the first and cancel any subsequent requests which come from the same initiating control.

This is working perfectly *on my machine*. However, it doesn't work on a colleague's machine or our staging server.

The crucial part of the problem is this: when the `PageRequestManager.initializeRequest` event is fired, the `args` parameter on my machine contains a populated `_postBackElement` object, whereas on other machines this property is *null*.

As far as we can see, all else is the same - the markup/code which triggers the request, the `<asp:ScriptManager />` declaration, the web.config...

So why is the PageRequestManager on other machines not populating this property, yet on my machine it *does* populate the property?